# exclude empty elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

in my sample xml file, i have this:

```
<AAA mandatory = "true"> good </AAA>
<BBB mandatory = "true"></BBB>
<CCC />
```

in the resulting xml, the result should be like this:

```
<AAA> good </AAA>
<BBB></BBB>
```

what should i put in my transformation file xslt to produce this xml?

currently, i have this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[(@mandatory='true' or (following-sibling::*[@mandatory='true' and string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0] or preceding-sibling::*[@mandatory='true' and string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0])) or descendant-or-self::*[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]]">
```

but this keeps displaying

```
 <CCC />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your XSLT on the input XML I do not get any output.
Your provided XML is not well formed and the XPATH in your "match" is too complicated I think.

I came up with a XSL 1.0 solution but I do not know if you can use that in XSL 2.0. I do not have experience with XSL 2.0.

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@mandatory='true']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<AAA mandatory="true"> good </AAA>
<BBB mandatory="true"/>
<CCC/>
</list>
```

gives this output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<AAA> good </AAA>
<BBB/>
</list>
```

I am not sure if you also want to check on the text length of an element or only on the attribute mandatory. I only check on the attribute in my XSL.

Comment: so which one of here removes the empty node that is not mandatory?

Comment: the <xsl:template match="/"> creates the <list> element to wrap the output. <xsl:template match="*[@mandatory='true']"> matches only the ones with @mandatory='true' and copies node + text. So all nodes not having the attribute are not copied. They are just left over. So no "deletion-command" is needed.